# Can a trace function be represented as a Hilbert-Schmidt product with the density matrix?

Tags: quantum-information, entropy, density-operator, trace

Given a trace function, say the von Neumann entropy $S(\rho) = - \mathrm{tr}(\rho \log \rho)$, can it be express as a matrix $M$ where $S(\rho) =  \mathrm{tr}(M^\dagger\rho)$ is given by the Hilbert-Schmidt inner product?

Comment: What is a "trace function"?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the case of the entropy, no. It's a nonlinear function in $\rho$, while your matrix multiplication is linear in $\rho$.